# Facebook SDK iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I downloaded Facebook SDK and my goal is to develop a complete Facebook client. I need to know if the SDK contains all methods and classes i have to use to develop a complete FB client. To see wall, news feed, friends, photos, videos and post and upload new element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.  However, those methods and classes are at a very low level.  In order to have a well-functioning app you will need to build some very complex classes and behaviors to create a "complete" FB app.

Some issues to consider - the FB app does nothing for you in terms of storing data on the device, does nothing for you regarding background operations such as downloading images while the user does other stuff, does nothing for you in terms of displaying data such as creating a tableview of posts, etc.  It essentially allows you to call most of the API methods from the site, and returns the data to you in JSON format.  It helps some in managing the access token needed for authentication, and it helps display some pre-made dialogs.

You must build everything else.

Comment: so, the Facebook sdk give me the chance to receive data in JSON format, right? My work will be to parse and after show this data to the user, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. You just need to know what permissions your app needs, then request that permissions to call the necessary API methods. Also the SDK offerse a built-in UI components to speed up your integration, like de Login button.